# How to create a separate time picker class

Tags: android

I created the time picker. But in my project, I have required to insert four time picker into the EditText fields.When clicking on the EditText,It will prompt thedailog to set the time.Its so lengthy to create the time picker in the Activity class.So I want to create a separate time picker class. I created the  TimePickerClass, but it shows error.
Please help me.

```
package com.sample.uiscreen;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TimePicker;


public class TimePickClass {


    private int mHour;
    private int mMinute;
    EditText time;
    public static final int TIME_DIALOG_ID = 0;
    MyActivity ma=null;




// the callback received when the user "sets" the time in the dialog
   public  TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =    
                    new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
       public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
           mHour = hourOfDay;
           mMinute = minute;
           time.setText(        
                    new StringBuilder()
                    .append(pad(mHour)).append(":")
                    .append(pad(mMinute)));}
     //pad method
       private String pad(int c) {
           if (c >= 10)
               return String.valueOf(c);
           else        return "0" + String.valueOf(c);       }    };

           protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
               switch (id) {    
               case TIME_DIALOG_ID:        
            return new TimePickerDialog(ma,
                    mTimeSetListener, mHour, mMinute, true);    }    
               return null; }





}
```

Comment: What error? Stack trace please...

Comment: I got solution how to create more than one time picker.But I created these in the Activity class.But I want to in a new class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code is as follows

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // capture our View elements
        settime1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time1);
        // add a click listener to the EditText
        settime1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDialog(TIME_ID1);            }        });

    settime2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.time2);
    settime2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(TIME_ID2);            }        });

       }

 // the callback received when the user "sets" the time in the dialogprivate 
    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener =    
        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            mHour = hourOfDay;
            mMinute = minute;
            updateDisplay();        }    };

            // updates the time we display in the 
            private void updateDisplay() {
                settime1.setText(        
                        new StringBuilder()
                        .append(pad(mHour))
                        .append(":")
                        .append(pad(mMinute)));}
            private static String pad(int c) {    if (c >= 10)        
                return String.valueOf(c);    
            else        return "0" + String.valueOf(c);}


                    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
                        switch (id) {
                        case TIME_ID1:
                            return new TimePickerDialog(this,
                                    mTimeSetListener, mHour, mMinute, true); 
                        case TIME_ID2:
                            return new TimePickerDialog(this,
                                    mTimeSetListener, mHour, mMinute, true);}
                        return null;}
```

Comment: Please any body knows ,tell me how to write these code in a separate class.I tried it. But unable to do it.